Force at least 5V from USB-C source without interfering with sink PD negociation
Context:
Consider a device with two USB-C receptacle. One is connected to a USB-C source (think laptop charger) and the other to a load (think laptop/smartphone). The device has a microcontroller that require 5V and there is a buck converter that can convert from 5+V down to 5V.
Goal:
I want the device to turn on as soon as the source cable is plugged in. I also want the load to negotiate the power it needs without interference from the device as if there was no device in the middle.
Approach:
My idea is to place pull-down resistors between the CC pins and the ground in the device and connect all the pins from one receptacle to the other as a cable would. This would signal the source that there is a sink and to start supplying 5V (the device does not need many amps to function).
Question:
I think that the pull-down should not interfere with the PD negotiation, as the laptop should also have these resistors. However, I am not sure, and I cannot find conclusive evidence to support this approach. Most design examples I came across propose to use a PD chip to propagate messages from the sink to the source but I would really like to find a simpler approach. I am looking for a confirmation that this could work or maybe some example schematic that achieves this goal.
Below is a schematic of the intended approach with the pull-down resistors between the CC pins and ground.


It will interfere. There is no way that is going to work. Except by having two independent Type-C ports negotiating connections and PD to allow power transfer between ports.
Both the "phone" device and your device will pull down one of the CC pins with two 5k1 resistors and this is an invalid resistance, it will not be detected as properly plugged in device.
Also as you have two Type-C receptacles in your device passing signals and power between them, it's already non-compliant.
Extending Type-C like that is not allowed.
The receptacle must not provide power until connection is detected. The reason is that two chargers may accidentally be plugged in and they are allowed to keep power on so there is a short circuit between two chargers.
Another reason is also that extending a cable with another is not allowed. is that you may put a 240W charger and 240W laptop together with 20V/3A cable, and it is not rated for 48V/5A. Also even if it were, it means you have two active E-marked cables connected together, but the PD protocol does not support more than one E-marked cable, when there is PD communication to cable, both cables will respond and that's going to break any negotiations.
Which would also mean that if both cables are active cables and require VCONN supply, the second cable is not going to get it through first cable.
Even if you omit the two 5k1 resistors and use a charger that always provides 5V and fully passive 20V/3A cables, as each standard compliant cable only has one CC wire, you would need to flip the plugs until the CC wire passes through both cables.
You want to draw "not many amps" but even 1A is too much. If there is 3A available and laptop draws 3A, there is no current available at all, and neither the supply or the laptop can know that.
Perhaps if you stated what you want to achieve there may be a proper solution. As it is now, it will only not work, is not compliant, and may damage your expensive chargers, phones and laptops etc.

The device is similar to a USB-C power meter except it also embarks a microcontroller that can perform some operations on the measured power. I have a few first versions that work well by tapping on the VBUS line but the device turns on only when both source and sink are connected. I want now to find a solution not have the device power on when either the charger or laptop is plugged in.
I understand why the resistor think does not work (forgot that resistor in parallel changes apparent values). Do you know an IC that can properly forward CC messages?

@Agriseld The power meter also contains a MCU that can perform some operations (like do measurements and print them to display). Any Type-C port controller or MCU including a Type-C port controller with Power Delivery should do it - but you need two to do it properly as you have two ports. The Amazon item is likely just powered via VBUS when present and likely cannot listen to PD messages, it simply measures voltage and current. It will also likely damage if devices try to negotiate more than 20V.

I know it contains an MCU, but I meant my device contains quite a bit more processing power (a Raspberry Pi 2 for now). I also know it does not look at PD messages; it is just an example of the kind of device I am building. The key point is that it is powered by VBUS when present, and I want mine to be able to ask for power from the charger or the laptop, whichever is connected, without interfering with subsequent power negotiation. I am looking at ICs that negotiate USB PD power but I cannot find one that propagates messages from one device to another. I am not sure it exists.

@Agriseld Such a thing may not exist. A MCU with two PD controllers needs to be bought and software written to forward negotiations to your liking needs to be written. However it would still mean the Raspberry Pi 2 consuming 400-1800mA at 5V which means you can't use a 65W supply with 65W laptop. This is the reason the Amazon units cost $10 and why they don't contain real circuitry for negotiation and why they don't consume hundreds of milliamps like the RPi2 does.

Thanks for your help. I think my problem went from "Sure I just need to update the schematic" to "I'm gonna need to talk to some professional about that" real quick.
